# Add UIView and animate it immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm adding a `UIView` to a view controller and want to it render and then immediately animate its movement, but a strange things is happening. The new view is being drawn at the destination where I want to animate it to and then animating to the origin that I had set it at. So it's essentially happening in reverse. Here's my code:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let square = UIView()
        square.backgroundColor = .red
        square.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(square)
        [square.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
         square.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
         square.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
         square.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            var frameCopy = square.frame
            frameCopy.origin.y -= 300
            square.frame = frameCopy
        }
    }

}
```

If I comment out the `UIView.animate` this is what gets created when I press the button, and this is what I expect

[image]

But then if I add the animation back in, this is what happens:

[image]

So as you can see the origin starts `-300` off centre and then moves to the centre whereas I want to to start on centre and then move `-300` off the screen. Can anyone help with this?

For the work I'm doing I need to add the view and then animate it immediately, I can't add the view previously and animate it later.

Comment: I don't know why you have this specific behaviour, but I know that you are not supposed to modify the frame when you have constraints. You should animate the `constant` of your centerY constraint instead.

Comment: You need to pick either AutoLayout + animate changes to constraints, or manual layout + animate frames

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mix `frame` based layout and AutoLayout as they will fight each other and whatever you're trying to do will be glitchy and not work well throughout iOS versions.

What you want to do is change the constraint set (deactivate old and activate new) and run `layoutIfNeeded` on the changed view in an animation block to perform animations.

Your case seems to be simpler and you can just capture your `centerYAnchor` constraint into a property and in the animation block do a `constraint.constant = 300` or equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

I found out it's to do with the drawing cycle and if you change it to:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let square = UIView()
        square.backgroundColor = .red
        square.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(square)
        [square.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
         square.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
         square.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
         square.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)].forEach { $0.isActive = true }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {
            square.layoutIfNeeded()
        } completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
                var frameCopy = square.frame
                frameCopy.origin.y -= 300
                square.frame = frameCopy
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Everything works as you'd expect

Comment: You still shouldn't mix `frame` changes with AutoLayout, use either one or the other.